# Highest rating comment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I'm trying to show the comment with the highest rating in the product show page but it shows # instead of the comment. Any ideas why?

```
#comment model
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :product

 scope :rating_desc, -> { order(rating: :desc) }
 scope :rating_asc, -> { order(rating: :asc) }
end

#product model
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :comments

  def highest_rating_comment
    comments.rating_desc.first
  end
end

#product show page
<%= @product.highest_rating_comment %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows a result of `inspect` method. You need to output a value of a rating field. Add changes to the product show page:

```
#product show page
<%= @product.highest_rating_comment.try(:rating) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output looks something like `"#<Comment:0x007fb9ea9561d0>"`, then what you're seeing is the result of calling `to_s` on `@product.highest_rating_comment`. Basically you're seeing the text representation of the object's location in memory.

What you probably want instead is the contents of the comment. Since you didn't provide your schema, I can't say what that field is called - perhaps `@product.highest_rating_comment.comment`?